# how set object or two value in mat-select

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, mat-select

I have this base class:

```js
    CodeDescription{
    //with all accessors method
    constructor(private _code: string, private _description: string) { }
```

In my HTML I do this `mat-select`.

list game is a  CodeDescription[] type

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="legacy" class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 w-100 p-3">
  <mat-label>{{ "APPLICATION.FORMS.GAME" | translate }}</mat-label>
  <mat-select formControlName="game">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of this.listGame" [value]="option.code"
      >{{option.description}}</mat-option
    >
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I use a service to call an and when I get results I need to associate result value to mat-select. In my ts I have this:

```js
this.gameControl= this.fb.group({
    game: [''],
```

So after I call api I load the values to mat-select and I do this:

```js
this.gameControl.get('game').setValue(new CodeDescription(this.result.codMan,this.result.descMan));
```

But the object is not printed correctly, but it is printed this `[object][object]`
Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `code` as your value, not the whole object.

```js
const val = new CodeDescription(this.result.codMan,this.result.descMan);
this.gameControl.get('game').setValue(val.code);
```